# Why does regression to the mean work?

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics

According to Wikipedia, regression towards the mean is "the phenomenon that arises if a sample point of a random variable is extreme (nearly an outlier), in which case a future point is likely to be closer to the mean or average."

But wouldn't you expect any future point to likely "be close to the mean" regardless simply because that's the expectation value of the rv? What does this have to do with the fact that the previous observation was an outlier and why does this affect/increase the likelihood that a future point be close to the mean?

Comment: you are right, any future point is likely to be close to the mean. if you were close to the mean in the beginning, you are likely to stay close to the mean, if yo were an outlier int he begging, you are likely to be close to the mean in the future, i.e., regress towards the mean.

Comment: I struggle a lot with this idea myself, especially given the observations being independent. I like to think of it as: the more extreme an outlier, the higher the probability the next observation will be closer to the mean than that outlier.

Comment: Consider two consecutive poker tournaments. Consider the winner of the first tournament. Since they won, they are probably more skilled than the average player, and they probably had better luck than the average player. In the next tournament, they will still be operating at the same (probably high) skill level, but their luck will on average be only mediocre, so on average we expect them to do better than average, but not as well as last time.

Comment: @nope why would it matter how extreme the outlier is. The probability that the next observation will be the mean or in the vicinity of the mean is the same

Comment: @fblundun Well in the case that they have more skill than average, the expectation value would be accordingly more. All you've said is the first time they got a result that exceeds the expectation value, and the second time got one more in line with it. But why does it matter what happened the first time? Even if they got a result more in line with the expectation value, you would still expect the same the second time around. Why would it be more likely or matter in any way if the first time was a bit of an outlier?

Comment: @xasthor "Well in the case that they have more skill than average, the expectation value would be accordingly more" - exactly. The fact that they won the 1st tournament is evidence of their skill, so our expectation of them going into the 2nd tournament should be higher than our expectation of the average player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do an example.

I'm going to flip a fair coin ten times. The expected number of heads is $5$. In statistics-speak:

$$
X \sim Binom(n=10, p=0.5)
$$

I do the flips and get the unusual result of $9$ heads and $1$ tail.

Now let's do it again. The expected number of heads is still five. That's regression to the mean.

> But wouldn't you expect any future point to likely "be close to the mean" regardless simply because that's the expectation value of the rv? What does this have to do with the fact that the previous observation was an outlier and why does this affect/increase the likelihood that a future point be close to the mean?

This is the point of regression to the mean, and it's important to understand this to understand regression to the mean vs gambler's fallacy. The whole point of regression to the mean is that the expected result is the expected value. Got a particularly high score (e.g., $9$ heads) the first time? Your next attempt is likely to be lower...because it's always likely to be lower ($5$ heads). Got a particularly low score the first time? Your next attempt is like to be higher...because it's always likely to be higher.

In the gambler's fallacy, the assumption is that the expected value on the next attempt (or an attempt coming up soon) is influenced by previous results. In my experiment above with the ten flips of the coin, the expected number of heads is $5$. Got three in a row with $10$ heads? We might start to question that the coin is fair (reasonable), but if we believe that coin is fair, the expected number of flips is $5$ rather than $2$ or $0$ to offset the streak of heads.

Answer (score 1):

It's a fairly loose concept, it applies in some situations and not others, depending on the assumptions & underlying distribution.

> But wouldn't you expect any future point to likely "be close to the mean" regardless simply because that's the expectation value of the rv?

Yes, if all RVs come from exactly the same distribution.

> What does this have to do with the fact that the previous observation was an outlier and why does this affect/increase the likelihood that a future point be close to the mean?

Your suspicion here is also correct - it doesn't affect/increase the likelihood, or change the RVs distribution at all. However, that's actually the point that the concept is trying to explain :-)

Say you take 10 students **with identical skill**, and give them a test, marks out of 100. Maybe their score is normally-distributed around 50, standard deviation of 10. One student gets 80/100, which is very unlikely, because their skill is the same as the others - this is a purely random event. If you test this person again, there is a 99.865% chance that they will get a worse result - not because this event modifies the probability distribution of their score; simply because their first result was itself unlikely.

Of course, if you test 10 students with very different skill levels, that's totally different - some students will naturally get higher marks than others. Regression to the mean **will not happen** (or at least, not so strongly).